# Construct Grammar for language {a^n b^m | 0 <= n <= m <= 2n}

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I am searching for a contextfree grammar with {a^n b^m | 0 <= n <= m <= 2n}.
So, the empty word (epsilon) is allowed as well. The only things I have to thing about it, that there are more b than a (or both equal) and not more than double the amount of h than a.
At the moment I have the following grammar:

```
S -> ab, aSbb, epsilon
```

It is doing well for the condition of having more b than a and it also has a maximum of 2n, but the problem is, it has exactly double the amount of b than a.
Is there an idea of how to solve that last problem for my grammar?
Thanks

Comment: If you add the production `S -> aSb` to your grammar (the production `S -> ab` then becomes unnecessary) then the grammar generates exactly the language you want. You can prove L(G) is in L and L is in L(G) by induction on the lengths of strings in each one. With this hint, you can probably post a full answer yourself or, if you have trouble finishing the proof, let me know and I will add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar is:
S -> aSb | aSbb | epsilon